# Batch File and Wait - MAXL

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subroutine

Have this batch that isn't running the MAXL until the end of the batch for some reason. I'm trying to have a log file output for the start of the procedure, run the MAXL, and then tell me when the file is finished.

```
REM Variables 1-9 assigned SET $1=variable1
CALL    :SUB_A
CALL    :SUB_B
CALL    :SUB_C

GOTO    :EOF

:SUB_A
    ECHO STARTING Rebuild_TEST - Started at %time% on %date% > D:\Logs\Rebuild_TEST_Start.log
EXIT /B
:SUB_C
    ECHO ENDING Rebuild_TEST - Started at %time% on %date% > D:\Logs\Rebuild_TEST_END.log
EXIT /B

:SUB_B
    ECHO STARTING REBUILD
    START "REBUILD" /W /B D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\startMaxl.bat Rebuild_TEST.msh %$1% %$2% %$3% %$4% %$5% %$6% %$7% %$8% %$9%
    ECHO ENDING REBUILD
EXIT /B

:EOF
```

What I'm seeing is the script goes through Subs A-C and then executes the MAXL. I was expecting Sub A to execute, Sub B to execute - Kicking off MAXL, then run SUB_C.

What am I doing wrong? 
I included /W to wait, /B to run the file in the current window so I don't have to intervene

If I run it with START "REBUILD" /W CMD /c maybe that'll work better?

Comment: use keyword `call` for the call to "startMaxl.bat", not `start`.  If you want to set the title bar to "REBUILD" while it is running, use the `title` command.. then set it back to whatever you like (usually either %COMSPEC% or "Command Prompt").

Comment: If I use `call` the startMAXL.bat won't run. The variable $9 has a % symbol which gets dropped if I use call @Señor CMasMas.

Comment: I can't believe that i missed that!  Scroll bar is your friend I guess.  $x is linux/bash syntax.  cmd.exe doesn't understand it.  For cmd.exe, your params are referenced with a single "%"..  Like this %1 %2 %3, not %$1%..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out. There were two issues, 1) MAXL.bat terminates the current process when the batch finishes - This requires a new terminal window to open 2) My password had a reserved character that drove me crazy. Echoing it helps but sometimes you'll need to encase the variable in "" when passed to maxl

StartMAXL.bat is used for Oracle Essbase data loads/rebuilds/etc. The .bat is usually 7 folders down.

To run MAXL, you list the full path to StartMAXL.bat and then pass a list of commands in a .msh file followed by the variables/parameters.

Save this as Essbase_Rebuild.cmd file
This is the basic MAXL Cmd line call

```
SET $1=[Essbase Username]
SET $2=[Essbase Password]
SET $3=localhost REM /*This is performed on the essbase server*/
SET $4=[Target Application Name]
SET $5=[Target App Cube Name]
SET $6=[source app]
SET $7=[source cube]
SET $8=[SQL Username]
SET "$9=[SQL password]" REM if you have special characters they might error in MAXL

D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\startMaxl.bat Essbase_Code_File.msh %$1% %$2% %$3% %$4% %$5% %$6% %$7% %$8% %$9%
```

Now for your Essbase_Code_File.msh file/or list of Essbase things you're doing

```
login $1 identified by $2 on $3;
spool on to 'D:\\Logs\\Essbase_Code_File.log';
/* do your MAXL commands */
spool off; 
logout;
exit;
```

The above method works for simple methods - Sometimes you might need to encase the %9% variables in "%9%" for MAXL to interpret the variable properly. Echo your variable in the .msh to view it in the command prompt by adding shell echo "$1"; to your .msh before login.

The more elegant version that took 3 months to figure out
Name it Essbase_Code_File.cmd

```
REM Parameters
SET $1=[Essbase Username]
-- repeat for your variables

CALL :SUB_A
CALL :SUB_B
CALL :SUB_C

GOTO :EOF

:SUB_A
ECHO Starting the Rebuild - Started @ %time% on %date% >D:\Logs\Rebuild_Start.log
EXIT /B

:SUB_B
ECHO STARTING REBUILD
START "ESSBASE_EXAMPLE" /W CMD /C D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\startMaxl.bat Essbase_Code_File.msh %$1% %$2% %$3% %$4% %$5% %$6% %$7% %$8% %$9%
EXIT /B

:SUB_C
ECHO Ending the Rebuild - Ending @ %time% on %date% >D:\Logs\Rebuild_End.log
EXIT /B

:EOF
```

I like this method because the command prompt doesn't get renamed - There's logging for start/end time, the rebuild occurs in a new window and then closes when finished,